# Xamarin froms Forms horizontal list view with buttons to move the dates to right, left

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

[image]

This is result of what I need to implement. If anyone had contact with something similar ,let me know

Comment: You need to put left and right button only, am I right?

Comment: @SümeyyaTuğçeArar yes to scroll the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

StackLayout using BindableLayout inside a ScrollView can be used for your requirement.

XAML code:

```
      <ScrollView
            x:Name="calender"
            Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackLayout
                BackgroundColor="Blue"
                BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Dates}"
                Orientation="Horizontal">
                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button
                            TextColor="White"
                            BackgroundColor="Blue"
                            Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

Button clicks:

```
    private void LeftButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (calender.ScrollX > 200)
            calender.ScrollToAsync(calender.ScrollX - 200, 0, true);
        else
            calender.ScrollToAsync(0, 0, true);
    }

    private void RightButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (calender.ScrollX < calender.ContentSize.Width - calender.Width - 200)
            calender.ScrollToAsync(calender.ScrollX + 200, 0, true);
        else
            calender.ScrollToAsync(calender.ContentSize.Width - calender.Width, 0, true);
    }
```

UI result:

[image]

Comment: Probably in a future, I will have some more questions so stand by, thanks once more

Comment: Maybe do you know how to make from your text in this button a commandparameter in button too ?

Comment: Do you have any ideas how to place more values in button than one, like on this screen which I pasted in my question, or make the same action on some clickable box with these values, number, date and this colorful circles

Comment: Use a stacklayout or any other layout with the view you want instead of button

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use CarouselView or ScrollView(horizontal), take a look in this post
[Xamarin Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-4-4/), i think you can achieve the best result with Carousel, but, both will work in this situation