# How to implement a listView "quick filtering" like week calendar view?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I've created a customer specific task management app with tasks placed on specific dates (and sometime hours), but here the date is important.

I'm using a listView and have a DatePicker setting for selected other dates than today. So far so good.

I would like to implement a week quick-filter option so that e.g., the dates of the current week is displayed at the top of the list view and a click on a certain date would filter the listView accordingly. Kind of a standard outlook-like week view.

How would I do this in the best way?
CustomControl that I put above the listView?
ViewPager control?

Any ideas or suggestions much appreciated.

P.S. I need to be able to target both Android and iOS.

Comment: A sketch what you're thinking about would be really helpful.

Comment: Try (this)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59734146/xamarin-froms-forms-horizontal-list-view-with-buttons-to-move-the-dates-to-right/59741246?noredirect=1#comment106021642_59741246] for displaying the dates of the week. For Sorting use the Where method from Linq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set two Properties in the ViewModel one for containing all the Items `EntireCollection` and another to store the Filtered Items `FilteredCollection`. On button click derive the Filtered item from entire list using Where.

**ViewModel**

```cs
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<ListItem> filteredCollection;

        public ObservableCollection<ListItem> FilteredCollection
        {
            get
            {
                return filteredCollection;
            }
            set
            {
                filteredCollection = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<ListItem> entireCollection;

        public ObservableCollection<ListItem> EntireCollection
        {
            get
            {
                return entireCollection;
            }
            set
            {
                entireCollection = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public ViewModel()
        { ...
            this.FilterCollection = this.EntireCollection;
          ...
        }
    }
```

**Button clicked**

```cs
        void Button_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime selectedDate = ((DateTime)((sender as VisualElement).BindingContext)).Date;

            viewModel.FilteredCollection = new ObservableCollection<ListItem>(viewModel.EntireCollection.Where(x =>
                {
                    if (DateTime.Equals(x.DateAdded, selectedDate))
                    {
                        var asd = x.DateAdded.Day;
                        return true;
                    }

                    return false;
                }));
        }
```

**XAML**

```cs
<StackLayout>
    <ScrollView
        x:Name="calender"
        Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackLayout
            BackgroundColor="Blue"
            BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Dates}"
            Orientation="Horizontal">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button
                        TextColor="White"
                        BackgroundColor="Blue"
                        Clicked="Button_Clicked"
                        Text="{Binding Day}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <ListView
        ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredCollection}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding DateAdded}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thank you. Just what I was missing. I've found a graphical layout which looks great. I'm modifying that and with your suggestion I'll be up and running in no time:https://github.com/mattmorgan6/ModernXamarinCalendar